# Operator == inconsistent in logical columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Please see the following reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(A=rep(0.3,10000))
DT[, B := runif(.N) < A]
DT[B == T, .N]
# [1] 3005
DT[, summary(B)]
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's
# logical    6995    3005       0
```

Everything looks fine and the count of "TRUE" values is the same for the 2 methods. Now replace col B with a new one.

```
DT[, B := runif(.N) < A]
DT[B == T, .N]
# [1] 3331
DT[, summary(B)]
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's
# logical    6981    3019       0
```

The count of 'T' in the column B is different!!! It is the same column but one method gives 3331 "TRUE" values and the other 3019.

When == is bypassed

```
DT[B != F, .N]
# [1] 3019
DT[, summary(B)]
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's
# logical    6981    3019       0
```

Which is correct again

I can reproduce it with data.table v1.94 and 1.9.5 on Windows 8.1 x64.

---

Here's a much easier reproducible example without `runif()`.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
DT = data.table(x = 1:5)
DT[, y := x <= 2L]
#    x     y
# 1: 1  TRUE
# 2: 2  TRUE
# 3: 3 FALSE
# 4: 4 FALSE
# 5: 5 FALSE

DT[y == TRUE, .N]
# [1] 2             <~~~~~~ correct result.

DT[, y := x <= 3L]
#    x     y
# 1: 1  TRUE
# 2: 2  TRUE
# 3: 3  TRUE
# 4: 4 FALSE
# 5: 5 FALSE

DT[y == TRUE, .N]
# [1] 2             <~~~~~~ incorrect result, should be 3!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now fixed in [v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) on GitHub.

> `:=` and `set*` now drop secondary keys (new in v1.9.4) so that `DT[x==y]` works again after a `:=` or `set*` without needing `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. Only `setkey()` was dropping secondary keys correctly. 23 tests added. Thanks to user36312 for reporting, [#885](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/885).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what @nrussell suggested.
This also could be a bug, according to @Eddi.
Below could be a temporary work-around.  Also suggested by @Arun. 
Please refer to the exchange of comments.

#### Case 1

```
> set.seed(123)
> DT <- data.table(A=rep(0.3,10000))
> DT[, B := runif(.N) < A]
> DT[B == T, .N]
[1] 3012
> DT[, summary(B)]
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical    6988    3012       0
```

#### Case 2

```
> set.seed(123)
> DT[, B := runif(.N) < A]
> DT[B == T, .N]
[1] 3012
> DT[, summary(B)]
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical    6988    3012       0
```

#### Case 3

```
> set.seed(123)
> DT[, B := runif(.N) < A]
> DT[B != F, .N]
[1] 3012
> DT[, summary(B)]
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical    6988    3012       0
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer @KFB. Your example works However I don't understand why when I don't set seed DT[B == T, .N] and DT[, summary(B)] give different results after col B is created. Does my example without set.seed before each runif works well?

Comment: @eddi, Sure your comment is understandable.  Nevertheless, I trust sometimes it's easier for green user, including myself, to "see" a case scenario to have better understanding.  Thus the illustration.  Thanks

Comment: @user36312, Suggest to google set.seed and runif.  There are a lot of answers. Exploration is the beginning of the interesting R-adventure.  Cheers.

Comment: This "answer" only hides the bug that OP has discovered. There is no need to put `set.seed` before every `runif` to have reproducible code, once at the top is enough.

Comment: @KFB Thank you for your help. As eddi replied above that this is probably a bug with data.table. I will file it in GitHub

Comment: @eddi, Could the illustration be a temporary work-around? Do think it serves a purpose.

Comment: @KFB one workaround is to disable the indexing, by e.g. doing `DT[(B == T), .N]`

Comment: Yep, bug - sorry. `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)` to turn off new feature. `:=` needs to remove any secondary indexes involving the updated column ...