# Strange behavior (bug?) with keys in R's data.table

Tags: r, key, data.table

I found what I believe to a bug in data.table that has been driving me crazy. I tried to create a minimal working example, but am having a hard time doing so-- so I've provided a data set for replication. I am using R version 3.1.0, data table 1.9.4.

Here's an example of the crux of the issue is this:

```
> log[select==1,list(trials=tabulate(select)),by=subj]
```

reports a value of "65" for subject 29

```
> log[select==1 & subj==29,list(trials=tabulate(select)),by=subj]
```

report a value of "85" for subject 29. Even without seeing the rest of the code, they should be identical, no?

---

Details: The data file "log.csv" available @ http://pastebin.com/ZwD7enxj

and my R code:

```
library(data.table)
log <- NULL
log <- fread('log.csv')

setkey(log,subj)

fun1 <- function() {
    log[,select:= 1]
    log[blocktime==10 | rt>10.0,select := 0]
    log[log[select==1,mean(correct),by=subj],avgACC := V1]
}

fun2 <- function () {
    log[blocktime==1 | blocktime==5,select := 1]
    log[select==1,list(trials=tabulate(select)),by=subj] 
}
```

Now if I run fun1() before fun2(), I see the erroneous behavior as mentioned above. If I run fun2() before fun1(), it appears to work fine.

Apparent fixes:
- remove the last line in fun1()
- add setkey(log,subj) at the begining of fun2() also fixes the problem

What exactly is going on here? If this is desired behavior, it is very confusing.

Comment: probably same bug as http://stackoverflow.com/q/26308072/817778 - try disabling the secondary indexing: `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`

Comment: Yes, that does appear to work! Though I don't completely understand the problem. Has this bug been reported, and is there somewhere I can track it? Does disabling secondary indexing have any major repercussions, assuming I don't explicitly use any tables with multiple keys?

Comment: I think it's essential to know the project page of a package/tool you're using, and useful to keep track of NEWS. It's all listed in the [CRAN listing of data.table package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

Comment: @Arun there is a github for data.table. I found the bug in question @ https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/885

Comment: @Arun Oh, looks like you're a developer for data.table. Thanks for all your hard work :)

Comment: Jeff, right, that's the one still open. Have a look at [bug fixes 6,7,8 under 1.9.5 news](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md) for the ones that have been fixed already by Matt.