# Change in data.table w.r.t to the subset-statement within the i-argument

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I re-run some code of mine and here I've been using the `x==min(x)` or some other function as `min()` within the `i`-argument of `data.table` to get the corresponding subset. Now it seems not to work if the resulting subset is not unique within the `i`-argument. I dont understand why?

Here a simple example:

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
> DT[v==min(v)]
   x y v
1: a 1 1
> DT[y==min(y)]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
> DT[y==1]
   x y v
1: a 1 1
2: b 1 4
3: c 1 7
```

`v==min(v)` works since there is only one line which will be returned.
`y==min(y)` does not work because there would be three lines which should have been returned.

Comment: Which version of `data.table` are you using? `DT[y==min(y)]` works for me (`data.table_1.9.2`)

Comment: This is most likely due to bug in 1.9.4 (due to new feature [automatic indexing](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/dacb9d1cac301de8d9ff)) which has since then been fixed. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26308072/559784).

Comment: Closed as duplicate. If it isn't the issue, please write back, and I'd be glad to reopen.